# Unity - NavMesh won't bake stairs

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

i have a huge problem while baking a stairs 3D model with my NavMesh in Unity 2019.3.12f1 for macOS.

Simply the stairs won't get part of the NavMesh as i expect.

Of course the stairs are static and walkable.

Do you know how can i correctly bake such kind of 3D models?

[image]

As you can see the stairs are completely ignored by the NavMesh despite i increased the Max Slope and Step Height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by reducing the Agent Radius and rebaking the NavMesh.

[image]